# With same parameters and methods name, how can the controller finds which one to be invoked in ASP.NET core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am following the tutorial posted on the Microsoft website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/details?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I just wonder once I click the delete button, how does it know which method or action should be invoked first? get or post? with the same parameters and action name
The code below might show you more details.

Thank you

```
 // GET: Movies/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(movie);
        }

        // POST: Movies/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Movie.Remove(movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Comment: GET request calls Delete(int? id) as GET is default, if you do not specify. POST request calls DeleteConfirmed(int id)

Comment: GET will be called first which returns a view probably asking you to confirm deletion. Then you do a POST to delete.

Comment: Haven't seen the source code for ASP. Net MVC core but I suspect that these methods are being called via reflection, not using ordinary polymorphism.  That's why the attributes decorating your controller methods are able to work the way they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, a GET request will usually return a View to perform an action, but it won't actually perform that action unless it is a POST request, e.g. a GET request to an action named Edit will grab the data to edit and display it. That's it. The changes are not saved to the database until a POST to the Edit action is submitted.

Overloaded methods are required to have different parameter signatures. Since the other scaffolded pairs of CRUD actions (except Delete) have different signatures, they can have the same name. But since both the GET and POST methods for the Delete action have the same parameter signature, one of them needs to be renamed, which is why the POST action is named DeleteConfirmed. However, having GET and POST methods named differently will break the routing built into MVC. Adding the ActionName("Delete") attribute fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

Routing depend on the HTTP Method  + The name + The Parameters

so, when you issue a GET request to `/Movies/Delete/5` it will use the first one.
When you issue a POST request to `/Movies/Delete/5`, it will use the second one.

If you have more than one POST method with different parameters, it will use the most specific. ex:

```
Delete(int id, bool confirm)
Delete(int id)
```

If you issue a POST request to /Movies/Delete/5, it will go for the second action, but if you change it to `/Movies/Delete/5?confirm=true`, it will go for the first one unless the parameter confirm was nullable, in this case it will throw an exception as it will not be able to determine which action to invoke